# How to delete every row that can be deleted?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, delete-row, sql-delete

Is there a way in SQL Server to delete every row that is deletable (does not have foreign keys preventing the deletion) without to have to know each foreign key reference?

I know I can check with `WHERE ID NOT IN (..)` or a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for each constraint, but is there something like

```
DELETE * FROM MyTable WITH CONTINUE_ON_ERROR
```

that would simply try to delete each record and if an error occurs ignore it and continue with the next record without rolling the transaction back?

Comment: No, there is no such feature. If you want to delete, it's *your job* to make sure those rows aren't referenced from somewhere

Comment: Seems like a strange request.  How do you know you are not deleting a FK not used today but you might need it in the future?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: "*Is there a way...?*" Yes. Is there a built-in or easy way? No.  You need to write your own code for that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `cursor` using `try catch` block:

```
DECLARE @id int

DECLARE curs CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR
    SELECT  ID
    FROM    MyTable

OPEN curs
FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN


        BEGIN TRY
            DELETE  FROM MyTable
            WHERE   id = @id
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
        END CATCH


        FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @id
    END


CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
```

Comment: This is what came into my head as well, but know it will be slow for any table of size.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some SQL that will write all the joins for you then return where the there is no match for the joins. Just point it at your table. Then if you want to delete then do delete from your table where pk_col IN (my dynamically created query)

```
DECLARE @TableName          VARCHAR(100) = 'yourTable',
        @LeftJoins          VARCHAR(MAX),
        @WherePredicates    VARCHAR(MAX);

WITH CTE_FK_PK
AS
(
    SELECT
        FK_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
        FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
        PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
        PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK
        ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
        ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU
        ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    INNER JOIN (
                SELECT
                    i1.TABLE_NAME,
                    i2.COLUMN_NAME
                FROM
                    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2
                    ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                WHERE
                    i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
               ) PT
        ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE PK.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
)


SELECT  @LeftJoins = COALESCE(@LeftJoins + CHAR(10),'') + 'LEFT JOIN ' + FK_Table + ' ON ' + FK_Table + '.' + FK_Column + ' = ' + PK_Table + '.' + PK_Column,
        @WherePredicates = COALESCE(@WherePredicates + CHAR(10) + 'AND ','') + FK_Table + '.' + FK_Column + ' IS NULL '
FROM CTE_FK_PK

SELECT 
'SELECT pk_col
FROM ' + @TableName + '
' + @LeftJoins + '
WHERE ' + @WherePredicates
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do this then check each constraint.

You could use a cursor to loop through each entry and wrap it in a try catch *but* this is horrible and will cause pain and misery for you and whoever has to support your application / database.